# OOTB Multiple contacts feature in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to access the new OOTB multiple contacts on tasks feature?

Answer (score 1):

you need to request the feature to be activated by your salesforce account manager. Once it is activated it cannot be deactivated. USE WITH CAUTION.

Comment: Why do you say to use with caution?  What are the drawbacks?

Comment: I say use with caution as there are side effects such as having to select having to select the contracts from a pick list as opposed to a simple lookup, this makes saving tasks slower. See here - 1:03 minutes in (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66Lqyw5E0gE)

Comment: Sorry should have said, I have the feature enabled and it works via the standard pages. Problem is I have been developing a custom visualforce page which is returning the standard lookup.

Comment: Yep, I read your question wrong too, missed the ref to Visualforce!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to talk to your account executive.

Go to https://na10.salesforce.com/setup/activitiesSetupPage.apexp?retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DActivity&setupid=HomeActivitiesSetupPage and check "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events."

While it is slower in some ways, you can get around the multi-select picklist by just putting in the person's name and clicking save.

Comment: Correct, I enabled myself. Issue is using feature via custom task entry page

Comment: Please update the question to indicate that you are using a custom task entry page, and please include all relevant code.